# Qualified business income in the US

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, foreign-income

While filing tax returns, I was asked, "Is this business effectively connected with the conduct of trade or business within the United States?" then I got a little confused.

I'm a US citizen working as a freelancer for the entire year in the US. I work with several clients and companies in foreign countries (e.g., selling a book on Amazon UK, working with an agency that provides services in France, etc.). I get paid to my US bank account.

Is my business considered effectively connected with conducting trade or business within the United States?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, effectively connected income (ECI) is a concept for non-residents. As a US citizen, you're automatically a US tax resident. In any case, income derived from business conducted within the United States is effectively connected to the United States by [definition](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/effectively-connected-income-eci). Business is conducted in the place where **you** are (not the clients).

Make sure you're not filing a non-resident return by mistake. As a US citizen, you should **not** file a "-NR" form.

Comment: Thank you so much, littleadv!